# Calculate sinusoidal regression of scatter plot

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression

I have weather data from the past four years on a scatter plot. The x-axis is time (in days), and y-axis is temperature. I want to use this to predict future weather values. The plot goes in a fashion of a sine wave, which leads me to believe I should use sinusoidal regression. Am I wrong to use this? If not, how can I calculate this? If I am wrong, what should I use to get what I want?

This is the code I have down right now, but I don't know were to go from here.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('csv/weather.csv')
df.plot(kind='scatter', x='Date time', y='Temperature', color='red')

plt.show()
```

[image: Scatter plot of temperatures and dates over 4 years]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the time series you're working with has a seasonal component. In such case, the advisable thing to do is to remove the seasonality from it before you fit any forecasting model. The main reason being that, you'd be adding unnecessary complexity to the model, which would most likely be struggling enough to model the sinusoidal behaviour to *also* do a good job with the underlying pattern that you *do* want to model.

The common approach is to detect the seasonality of the signal by taking the autocorrelation, and removing it by taking the corresponding lagged difference.

You might find [this blog post](https://machinelearningmastery.com/remove-trends-seasonality-difference-transform-python/) useful, which goes through this with a similar example.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on how I can implement this into my code? I've looked at the blog post, and I am still a little confused. Thank you.